# IndexOutOfBoundsException when call to getForegroundTaskPackageName()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have been receiving this error with a sony devices.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver .ui.broadcast.InternetConnectionBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
   at cat.bcn.vincles.ui.Utils.SystemHelper.getForegroundTask(SystemHelper.java:378)
   at cat.bcn.vincles.ui.Utils.SystemHelper.getForegroundTaskPackageName(SystemHelper.java:409)
   at cat.bcn.vincles.ui.broadcast.InternetConnectionBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(InternetConnectionBroadcastReceiver.java:22)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at          com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

This is the code where I'm calling to getForegroundTaskPackageName().

```
SystemHelper sh = SystemHelper.getInstance(context);
String foregroundAppPackageName = sh.getForegroundTaskPackageName();
```

For add some more of information this code is inside of **BroadcastReceiver** and I'm using this because I need to know if the app is in foreground or not.

I don't know what it's happens with that because only It happens with one device.

EDIT:

I'm going to put all code of this class

```
public class InternetConnectionBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);

    SystemHelper sh = SystemHelper.getInstance(context);
    String foregroundAppPackageName = sh.getForegroundTaskPackageName();

    boolean appInForeground = false;
    boolean appInteractive = false;

    if (foregroundAppPackageName.equals(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName())) {
        appInForeground = true;
    }

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        appInteractive = powerManager.isScreenOn();

    if (status == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        if (appInForeground && appInteractive) {
            startNoInternetConnectionActivity();
        }
    } else {
        if (appInForeground && appInteractive) {
            internetConnectionRestored();
        }
    }

}

private void startNoInternetConnectionActivity() {
    VinclesApplication.getInstance().showNoInternet();
}

private void internetConnectionRestored() {
    VinclesApplication.getInstance().finishNoInternetActivity();
}
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
/**
 * returning the last running task (usually a foreground activity)
 * 
 * @return
 */
public RunningTaskInfo getForegroundTask()
{
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you do in `getForegroundTask()` on `SystemHelper.java:378` ?

Comment: @alfasin I don't call to this method, I think that this method is called by getForegroundTaskPackegeName() internally.

Comment: Look at the stacktrace: `onReceive() -> getForegroundTaskPackageName() -> getForegroundTask()` and `SystemHelper` class is one of your classes, no?

Comment: @alfasin I have edited the post and I added the code of the class.

Comment: You didn't post the code of `SystemHelper`. That's where it's all happening...

Comment: @alfasin I have edited the post again and I added the code but I think that I found the error Thanks! I need to catch this exception.

Comment: Not to catch the exception but to check the size of `am.getRunningTasks(1)` before you try to access `.get(0)` ;)

Comment: @alfasin If you want create an answer and I will accept it and put the correct answer. :D

Comment: I would, but since this question is very specific to your code, the right thing to do would actually be to delete it...